# Required: Float, Found: Float []. Compatibility issue

Tags: java

I need to store values of a table in an array, but I can't because the values are floats and it is being given an array. Basically, the lines that are giving me error are:

```
float[] floatArray = new float[columnCount]; 
floatArray[i] = dataModel.getFloats(nextRow, i, length);
```

`columnCount` needs to be an `int` because it is used for the for loop as well as being taken from another class. How do I make the 2nd line compatible. It is saying it requires a `float` (which is what `dataModel` outputs) but sees a `float[]`.

I can try to be more helpful if I am not clear.

Comment: did you want a 2d array? because you are trying to store a list in a list

Comment: What is the signature of method `dataModel.getFloats()`?

Answer (score 3):

The error is "Required: Float, Found: Float []."

It means you're trying to set `float[]` into a `float` variable. You misunderstood the error message.

I believe your `getFloats()` is returning `float[]`, not `float`. So the correct assignment is:

```
float[] floatArray = dataModel.getFloats(nextRow, i, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `getFloats()` returns a single float, and all previous variables are defined, you can store all of the values into the array like this:

```
float[] floatArray = new float[columnCount];
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_FLOATS; i++) {
    floatArray[i] = dataModel.getFloats(nextRow, i, length);
}
```

Conversely, if `getFloats()` returns a `float[]`, then you can peform this operation on a single row:

```
float[] floatArray = dataModel.getFloats(nextRow, i, length);
```

Comment: I assumed he left it out and showed the definition and the assignment, but good point.